# Selecting a table row who's siblings are hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a html table with the following structure:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr><th>heading1</th></tr>
  <tr style="display: none"> <td>data1</td></tr>
  <tr style="display: none"> <td>data1</td></tr>
</tbody>

<tbody>
  <tr><th>heading2</th></tr>
  <tr> <td>data1</td></tr>
  <tr style="display: none"> <td>data1</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am looking for a way to select a row in that table that holds  heading, but whose all siblings are hidden, in this example, heading2 wouldn't be selected because only one row is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tr = $('tr:first-child').filter(function() {
  return $(this).siblings(':hidden').length == $(this).siblings().length;
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u6Qj5/1/

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do:

```
$("th").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parent().nextAll().is(":visible");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fpgs/

Comment: @KevinBowersox Thanks.  Just seemed slightly more efficient to check that none were visible rather than that all were hidden.

Comment: I like how you step up to the parent in the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table th').filter(function() {
  var $tr = $(this).parent().siblings('tr');
  return $tr.filter(':hidden').length == $tr.length;
}).parent();
```